# Is it considered inappropriate to tell someone to accept your answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

If the OP has commented "Thanks!" or "Solved!" (something like that) on my answer, will it be considered inappropriate to leave a comment telling him to hit the tick button?

Comment: Telling would probably be considered rude. Suggesting is OK - the OP may just not know how the site works.

Comment: I normally just provide a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, which covers both: 1. Not adding unnecessary comments; and 2. Upvoting/accepting instead. Particularly on questions with multiple answers, it can look a bit sketchy to be saying *"please accept my answer"*!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an answer has solved OP's issue, it's *expected* from OP that (s)he should accept the best among the provided answer.

However, many a times, OP does not know *how to* accept. IMHO, "telling" someone what  to do in this case maybe considered rude. However. you can always "guide" them in proper way through leaving a polite comment which points them to the correct direction. That is acceptable.

I basically Add a reply to OP's "thanks" or "solved" comments, saying either

1. Short version, for not-so-newcomers

> You're welcome . :-) BTW, you can consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.

or,

2. For absolute newbies,

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page and also [ask] questions here? and [What do I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

---

<sup>Note: Don't forget the links. [ask] is a magic-tag, FWIW.:-)</sup>

Comment: Or what I usually do "Do you need more help? If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Also see [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)"